# Is a Javascript this.object.property = object.property passed by reference or value; breaking garbage collector/memory leak

Tags: javascript, object, memory-leaks, reference

We are running into an issue in which we have a memory leak and we are having difficulty isolating it.  The problem is we have code in a custom engine with limited diagnostics.

We are trying to wrap our heads around if a section of our code is passing information by value (good) or by reference (bad).  The developer of our engine states if we pass by reference there is a chance for a local variable to gain permanence and thus the garbage collector is no longer able to free the memory.

Below is an abridged psuedo version of the code:

```
Device:{
   name,
   ip
},
func1: function(var1, var2){
   var obj1 = {name:"",ip:""};

   //Do Stuff

   this.func2(obj1);

},
func2: function(obj2){

   //Do More Stuff

   this.Device.name = obj2.name
   this.Device.ip = obj2.ip

}
```

Does the above create this 'permanence' which prevents obj2/obj1 from being garbage collected after the termination of the local scope?

---

Edit 1:

The JS specific engine inside their larger custom compiler is based on qt 4.8

Here is the actual code aka the stuff with some of the error checking pulled out for clarity. QMedialon being the bits that pass variables in and out of the JavaScript portion of the engine to their custom portion.

```
Device: {
    Processed_Name: "",
    Processed_IP: "",
    Processed_Mute: "",
    Processed_Pause: "",
    Processed_Volume: "",
    Processed_Status: "",
    Debug: "",
    Debug2: "",
    Error: ""
},

ProcessInput: function (rawFrame,rawIP) {
//$$NAME$$*$$State$$+$$PAUSED$$+$$CH1_MUTE_STATUS$$+$$CH1_VOLUME$$^
    var ter = {name:" ", status:0, pause:0, mute:0, volume:0, ip:""};

    var x = rawFrame.indexOf("*");
    ter.name = rawFrame.slice(0,x); 
    ter.ip = rawIP;     
    rawFrame = rawFrame.slice(x + 1,(rawFrame.length - 1));

    var splitter = rawFrame.split("+");
    ter.status = splitter[0];
    ter.pause = splitter[1];
    ter.mute = splitter[2];
    ter.volume = splitter[3];
    if(ter.status){
        this._BrightWrite(ter);
    }
},
_BrightWrite: function(obj){
    this.Device.Processed_Name = obj.name;
    var key = this._KeyGen(obj.name,"-");

    this.Device.Processed_Status = obj.status;
    QMedialon.SetValue("STATUS_AV_"+key,obj.status);
    QMedialon.SetValue("TECH_MUTE_"+key,obj.status + ".Text");

    this.Device.Processed_IP = obj.ip;
    QMedialon.SetValue("TECH_IP_"+key,obj.ip + ".Text");

    this.Device.Processed_Mute = obj.mute;
    QMedialon.SetValue("MUTE_AV_"+key,obj.mute);
    QMedialon.SetValue("TECH_MUTE_"+key,obj.mute + ".Text");

    this.Device.Processed_Pause = obj.pause;
    QMedialon.SetValue("PAUSE_AV_"+key,obj.pause);
    QMedialon.SetValue("TECH_PAUSE_"+key,obj.pause + ".Text");

    this.Device.Processed_Volume = obj.volume;
    QMedialon.SetValue("VOLUME_AV_"+key,obj.volume);
    QMedialon.SetValue("TECH_VOL_"+key,obj.volume + ".Text");

    QMedialon.SetValue("POLLING_AV_"+key,0);

    if(QMedialon.GetValueAsInteger("A_ACTIVE_AV") == key){

        if(obj.pause == 1){
            QMedialon.SetValue("BSC_DSP_STATUS.Text","Paused"); 
        }
        else{
            QMedialon.SetValue("BSC_DSP_STATUS.Text",this._StatusTranslate(parseInt(obj.status)));  
        }               
        this._SliderHandler(key);   
    }

},
```

Comment: I think it's impossible to give a  definitive answer from that code, but `obj1` itself can be garbage collected.

Comment: Well ... can't you ask the developer of that engine? He should know what it does ... right?

Comment: If you use a custom engine, it probably also has a custom garbage collector. We don't know what it does, and although we can say that your `func2` *should* not keep a reference to its argument, that garbage collector may be buggy.

Comment: It might very well depend a lot on what `//Do More Stuff` exactly does.

Comment: I added in the actual code into an edit as well as the info the developer gave on the core JS engine.

Answer (score 1):

> The developer of our engine states if we pass by reference there is a chance for a local variable to gain permanence and thus the garbage collector is no longer able to free the memory.

It should not.

As a rule of thumb: Every value that can be accessed somehow programmatically, can not be garbage collected (as you might still need it). If some value cannot be accessed, it will be garbage collected no matter how it was passed around before (if the engine is doing its job correctly).

> Does the above create this 'permanence' which prevents `obj2` / `obj1` from being garbage collected after the termination of the local scope?

No. After both functions ended execution, there is no way to access `obj2`, or `obj1`, as the local variables do not exist anymore. Thus, the object they are *referencing* to is viable for GC'ing.

> The problem is we have code in a *custom engine* with limited diagnostics.

Yes, that's the problem.